# Extension on space using trace of Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

The exercise is the following:

Let $\Omega$ be open bounded with smooth border, $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $v \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^d\backslash \bar{\Omega})$. One defines $w$ as $u$ on $\Omega$ and $v$ on $\mathbb{R}\backslash \bar{\Omega}$.

Prove that $w$ is in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ if and only if $\operatorname{trace}(u) = \operatorname{trace}(v)$.

I don‘t understand why $w$ shouldn‘t be in $W^{1,p}$ i.e. which part of the definition of $W^{1,p}$ doesn‘t work out.

Can someone help me?

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ when $x\in (-1, 0)$ and $f(x)  =1 $ when $x\in (0,1)$. Is this in $W^{1,p}(-1, 1)$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This means that the new function cannot have a jump across the boundary. The 1-D example in the previous comment illustrates this.

Comment: Thanks, these answers helped!